# Ansible - /etc/profile.d scripts

Tags: ansible

I defined a `envs.sh` script inside the `/etc/profile.d/` folder.
When executing a `ansible-playbook`, I'm trying to get the value of this env var but it instead throws me an error:

Ansible test:

```
debug: msg="{{ ansible_env.NGN_VAL }} is an environment variable"
```

Error:

```
fatal: [xxx.yyy.zzz.kkk] => One or more undefined variables: 'dict object' has no attribute 'NGN_VAL'

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Why it doesn't execute the scripts inside that folder? When I connect through `ssh`, I echo it and it displays its value. How do I set remote environment variables and obtain them during ansible execution?

Thanks

Comment: What is the linux distribution? Can you post the output of `ls -l /etc/profile.d/envs.sh` ? Are the `ssh user` and `ansible user` same?

Comment: You could use environment: at the start of your playbook. But if you want use variables from a file use a shell: source /etc/profile.d/envs.sh && command .... But this solution only work in one task. The best way is with the environment module

Comment: @helloV, it is a ubuntu/trusty64 14.04. Inside the file I am only exporting a variable: `export NGN_VAL=myvalue`. I think the users are the same, yes. I was trying to keep a password inside this variable. But I've just seen that for passwords, ansible has a solution called `Vaults`. I'm going to experiment it, but anyway if you know why my variables are not being loaded, you can answer here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Test with this if you want catch the environment variable.

```
[jenkins@scsblnx-828575 jenkins]$ cat mypass
export MYPASSWD=3455637

[jenkins@scsblnx-828575 jenkins]$ cat test.yml
- hosts: all
  user: jenkins
  tasks:
    - name: Test variables.
      shell: source /apps/opt/jenkins/mypass && echo $MYPASSWD
      register: myenvpass

    - debug: var=myenvpass.stdout

[jenkins@scsblnx-828575 jenkins]$ ansible-playbook -i hosts test.yml    

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [Test variables.] *********************************************************
changed: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "myenvpass.stdout": "3455637"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Hi Raul! It's important for me that the variable is only inside my remote server. It's a password and I don't want to put it in plain text inside my playbook. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I edit my answer, tell me if is the solution that you need.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view you can accomplish using a mix of [ansible vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html) and system environment variables.

Create and encrypt a file with ansible vault (this is where you put the content of your remote env variable):

```
$ ansible-vault create vars_environment.yml
```

Put your password to encrypt this file and write content of your variable, for example:

```
ngn_val: supersecret
```

I use to load my permanent environment variables in `/etc/profile.d` directory but they are more paths:

- `/etc/profile.d`
- `/etc/profile`
- `/etc/environment`
- `~/.profile`

It is a good way to write a [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_templating.html) in your playbook, although your can use the [copy module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/copy_module.html):

```
---
# environment.yml
- name: Get enviroment variable server
  hosts: debian.siccamdb.sm
  vars: 
    dest_profile_environment: /etc/profile.d/environment.sh
  vars_files:
    - vars_environment.yml
  tasks:
    - name: "Template {{ dest_profile_enviroment }}"
      template:
        src: environment.sh.j2
        dest: "{{ dest_profile_environment }}"
        mode: '0644'
    - name: Load env variable
      shell: ". {{ dest_profile_environment }} && echo $NGN_VAL"
      register: env_variable
    - name: Debug env variable
      debug:
        var: env_variable.stdout_lines[0]
```

The important thing here is in the shell task because you have to source your environment variable and the use it by the register [keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html) which can be used to capture the output of a command in a variable.

This is the template's content in this example the file `environment.sh.j2`:

```
export NGN_VAL={{ ngn_val }}
```

Type your password o the `vars_environment.yml` file after run the playbook:

```
ansible-playbook --vault-id @prompt environment.yml
```

The output is the following:

```
PLAY [Get enviroment variable server] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [debian.siccamdb.sm]

TASK [Template {{ dest_profile_enviroment }}] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [debian.siccamdb.sm]

TASK [Load env variable] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [debian.siccamdb.sm]

TASK [Debug env variable] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [debian.siccamdb.sm] => {
    "env_variable.stdout_lines[0]": "supersecret"
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
debian.siccamdb.sm         : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Another way to accomplish is using [custom facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#adding-custom-facts) in your remote server. This is a good practice if you want to leave the content of your variable in the remote server and using in playbooks without the needs of ansible vault.